# Oracle MAF - using external libraries (jars)

Tags: java, oracle, cross-platform, oracle-maf, oracle-adf-mobile

The project I am trying to develop is a cross-platform mobile app based on Oracle MAF technology.

In this particular project, I have to use very sophisticated Java code.

We have tried to use Codename One before, but it has a problem of importing external libraries because of very poor base Java classes support.

The question is: does Oracle MAF allow developers import any libraries, or are there any restrictions on the external code to be used in the project?

I understand that the code has to be translated to some ios-based code for the iOS version of the app. Thus the tools for translation the code could have restrictions in terms of supported base Java classes.